# Ways to say "to take something by hand" in English

Tags: word-usage, difference, vocabulary

I would like to know how to say "to take something by hand" in these contexts. For example, we have: Pick, grab, take, etc. And I wish to know which word would fit the best in these sentences

> I *took/grabbed/picked,...* the book and sat on a chair.
>
> Ok. So, I *pick, took, grab,...* the flashlight from the shelf and give to one of you?
>
> I *picked,grabbed,took..* the stick from ground!

I just would like point out an observation first:

> Please, do not think that this is a question regarding only the difference between these 3 words. I would like to know more words/ phrasal verbs that mean the same thing as "to take something by hand" and know their differences between each other (for example: I want to know the difference between grab and pick, take and pick, etc...). And I want to use them correctly.

Comment: Go here: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/grab?s=t

Comment: It's _pick up_. You pick (pluck) a flower, or pick (choose) a chocolate from the box, but taking an object _in your_ hand is picking it up.